# SQL Merge rows - string data type

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Does anyone have any idea how to construct a select statement querying a temp table that contains the following data:

```
Code    |Col1     | Col2| Col3
----------------------------------------
ABCD    |AAASTRING|NULL |  NULL
ABCD    |NULL     |BBBSTRING |  NULL
ABCD    |NULL     |NULL |  CCCSTRING
```

... that will merge the results as follows?

```
Code    |Col1   | Col2 | Col3
---------------------------------------
ABCD    |AAASTRING| BBBSTRING | CCCSTRING
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which database are you using? Your seem to have been a bit overzealous when tagging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Code,
    MAX(Col1) AS Col1,
    MAX(Col2) AS Col2,
    MAX(Col3) AS Col3
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Code
```